# lein REPL server launch timed out

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, datomic

in a liberator based clojure project we are using datomic as DB. After migrating our local dev DB to a S3 hosted one and adding the needed dependencies on our project.clj we cannot launch the REPL but the Liberator stack runs fine through `lein run`

My guess is that the DB connection is messing things up, so, the question is, how can  I somehow "debug" or figure out what's the reason of this `lein repl` timeout?

My project.clj

```
(defproject myproject "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :main myproject.core
  :jvm-opts ["-Xmx1G"]
  :datomic {:schemas ["resources" ["myproject-schema.edn" ]]}
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.10"]]
  ; cp bin/transactor config/samples/free-transactor-template.properties resources/transactor.properties
  :profiles {:dev
             {:datomic {
                        ; :config resources/transactor.properties
                        ; :db-uri "datomic:free://127.0.0.1:4334/myproject"}
                        :db-uri "datomic:ddb://us-east-1/datomica/myproject"}

 :dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"]
                             [midje "1.5.1"]
                             ]
              }
             }
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.4556"]
                 ; [com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.4470"]
                 [com.cemerick/friend "0.2.0"]
                 [liberator "0.10.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.13"]
                 [cheshire "5.1.1"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.0"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [url62 "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [clj-http "0.7.8"]
                 [org.clojars.nathell/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [com.taoensso/timbre "3.0.0-RC4"]
                 [clj-aws-s3 "0.3.8"]
                 [image-resizer "0.1.5"]
                 [pandect "0.3.1"]
                 [base64-clj "0.1.1"]
                 ]
    :ring {
           :handler myproject.core
           }
)
```

My profiles.clj

```
cat ~/.lein/profiles.clj                                                           
{:user {:dependencies [[slamhound "1.5.0"]]
        :aliases {"slamhound"["run" "-m" "slam.hound"]}
        :plugins [[lein-datomic "0.2.0"]
                  [lein-midje "3.0.0"]
                                  [lein-html5-docs "2.0.0"]
                                  [lein-pprint "1.1.2-SNAPSHOT"]]
                ; :datomic {:install-location "/opt/datomic-free"}
                :datomic {:install-location "/opt/datomic-pro/"}
                }
}%
```

My .zshrc

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/user:/opt/datomic-pro:.
```

My env

```
Leiningen 2.3.3 on Java 1.7.0_25 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Linux 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It can sometimes take a while for all the ducks to be in order. Specify `:repl-options` in your project.clj file with a longer time-out like this:

```
:repl-options {
             ;; If nREPL takes too long to load it may timeout,
             ;; increase this to wait longer before timing out.
             ;; Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds)
             :timeout 120000
             }
```

Hopefully that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this answer also helped me configure nREPL as I wasn't aware of this option.

Answer (score 4):

The reason was the multiple redefinition and evaluation of the Datomic connection among several files

```
(def conn (d/connect DATOMIC_URI))
```

The solution to this topic has been already discussed at [How to deal with a variable in a library that needs to be set outside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683724/how-to-deal-with-a-variable-in-a-library-that-needs-to-be-set-outside-of-it/20686587#20686587)

Comment: This problem is also well solved by Stuart Sierra's Component pattern/lib.

Answer (score 2):

set timeout value in field :repl-options in project.clj,the default is 30000(30s).
for example :

```
:repl-options{:timeout 120000}
```