# lein repl stopped working

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I hadn't used `lein repl` for a couple days on my home computer.

Now, when I try running it up, it times out.

Running `bash -x lein repl` I see it hangs at:

```
+ java -Xbootclasspath/a:/.../leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar \
       -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
       -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false \
       -Dmaven.wagon.rto=10000 -XX:+TieredCompilation \
       -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dleiningen.original.pwd=/... \
       -Dleiningen.script=/opt/local/bin/lein \
       -classpath /.../leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar \
       clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main repl

REPL server launch timed out.
+ EXIT_CODE=1
```

If I try just running the following, I manage to get a basic REPL:

```
java -classpath /.../leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar clojure.main
```

---

---

***Strangely enough, just tried shutting down my wifi based on another posting, and now it works?***

---

---

Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks, Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure out what the issue was in the end.

Some process had truncated my hosts file a couple of days ago.

Reinstated the hosts file, and everything went back to normal. Happy days :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the timeout as explained here: [lein REPL server launch timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736952/lein-repl-server-launch-timed-out)

If that doesnt work, I would suggest connecting with a jconsole or doing a thread dump to see where is the process waiting for.